# How to break users into managers and attendees?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

First here's my current setup:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
   has_many :events
end
```

**models/event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So, this works in the sense that a user have many events that s/he can CRUD. Anyone that is not logged in can only view and list all the events.

From this initial setup, I now have another set of users that are attendees and the current users are now actually event managers instead of just a generic user. Essentially, I now have two models that are both users (since they can both log in/sign up and have the same fields) and I was thinking that event should read something like:

**models/event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager
  has_many :attendees, :through => :attendance # attendance is a join model
end
```

but I don't want to create a separate table for managers and attendees and I was thinking of sub classing the user model but I'm not particularly sure about how to go about it. I was looking into the `:as` and `:polymorphic` parameters in AR but I'm still not quite sure on how to do it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *Single Table Inheritance*. [Here is one resource on the subject](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/). There are many more. Just [google for "Rails Single Table Inheritance"](http://www.google.com/?q=rails+single+table+inheritance#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=rails+single+table+inheritance&btnK=Google+Search&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=1&biw=1191&bih=1059&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b).